# JQuery Datatables server side filtering by data range using SSP Class in php

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using [Jquery DataTables Server side Processing](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) just the way they show here.

I need to add a datepicker so I can filter by **data range**. One of my DB columns is a timestamp type. I searched google, found some not really useful information, and nothing shows me how to handle it all the way from the client all the way to the server.

I also read the [plug-in filtering date-range](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_numbers) and couldn't make sense of it.

I could really use some help.

Comment: Which API version are you using?  Could you post your attempt in a fiddle please?

Comment: I dont even remember why I asked this, was too long ago, should I just delete this ?

Comment: Rather add an answer, may help someone in future :)